# Do Sabre InstaFlights API Responses In Test Environment Not Use Real Prices?

Tags: sabre, fare

I'm trying to cross-check the prices returned by calls to the Sabre InstaFlights API against prices I would find on Google Flights, and it seems that the API response contains real flights but fake pricing info. Usually much much cheaper than what I find on Google Flights. Is it true that these are fake prices but real flights? And if so, is this only because I'm using a Test environment?

For example, the cheapest flight returned for a certain roundtrip from NYC to CHI says it found a $128.60 fare, but this same roundtrip is $311 on Google Flights.

RequestURI:

https://api.test.sabre.com/v1/shop/flights?origin=NYC&destination=CHI&departuredate=2018-03-02&returndate=2018-03-04&outbounddeparturewindow=16002100&inboundarrivalwindow=14002359&onlineitinerariesonly=N&limit=10&offset=1&eticketsonly=N&sortby=totalfare&order=asc&sortby2=departuretime&order2=asc&pointofsalecountry=US

Response Body:

```
{
"PricedItineraries": [{
    "AirItinerary": {
        "OriginDestinationOptions": {
            "OriginDestinationOption": [{
                "FlightSegment": [{
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LGA"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "ORD"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "AA"
                    },
                    "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                        "GMTOffset": -6
                    },
                    "TPA_Extensions": {
                        "eTicket": {
                            "Ind": true
                        }
                    },
                    "StopQuantity": 0,
                    "ElapsedTime": 182,
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "B",
                    "MarriageGrp": "O",
                    "Equipment": {
                        "AirEquipType": 738
                    },
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2018-03-02T16:30:00",
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-03-02T18:32:00",
                    "FlightNumber": 343,
                    "OnTimePerformance": {
                        "Level": 6
                    },
                    "OperatingAirline": {
                        "FlightNumber": 343,
                        "Code": "AA"
                    },
                    "DepartureTimeZone": {
                        "GMTOffset": -5
                    }
                }],
                "ElapsedTime": 182
            }, {
                "FlightSegment": [{
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "ORD"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "LGA"
                    },
                    "MarketingAirline": {
                        "Code": "AA"
                    },
                    "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                        "GMTOffset": -5
                    },
                    "TPA_Extensions": {
                        "eTicket": {
                            "Ind": true
                        }
                    },
                    "StopQuantity": 0,
                    "ElapsedTime": 130,
                    "ResBookDesigCode": "B",
                    "MarriageGrp": "O",
                    "Equipment": {
                        "AirEquipType": 738
                    },
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2018-03-04T15:30:00",
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2018-03-04T18:40:00",
                    "FlightNumber": 364,
                    "OnTimePerformance": {
                        "Level": 6
                    },
                    "OperatingAirline": {
                        "FlightNumber": 364,
                        "Code": "AA"
                    },
                    "DepartureTimeZone": {
                        "GMTOffset": -6
                    }
                }],
                "ElapsedTime": 130
            }]
        },
        "DirectionInd": "Return"
    },
    "AlternateAirport": true,
    "TPA_Extensions": {
        "ValidatingCarrier": {
            "Code": "AA"
        }
    },
    "SequenceNumber": 3,
    "AirItineraryPricingInfo": {
        "AlternateCityOption": true,
        "PTC_FareBreakdowns": {
            "PTC_FareBreakdown": {
                "FareBasisCodes": {
                    "FareBasisCode": [{
                        "BookingCode": "B",
                        "DepartureAirportCode": "LGA",
                        "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                        "ArrivalAirportCode": "ORD",
                        "content": "O0ELZNB3"
                    }, {
                        "BookingCode": "B",
                        "DepartureAirportCode": "ORD",
                        "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                        "ArrivalAirportCode": "LGA",
                        "content": "O0ELZNB3"
                    }]
                },
                "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "Code": "ADT"
                },
                "PassengerFare": {
                    "FareConstruction": {
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                        "Amount": 93.02
                    },
                    "TotalFare": {
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "Amount": "128.60"
                    },
                    "Taxes": {
                        "TotalTax": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": 35.58
                        },
                        "Tax": [{
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 1,
                            "TaxCode": "AY",
                            "Amount": 11.2
                        }, {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                            "TaxCode": "XF",
                            "Amount": 9
                        }, {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 1,
                            "TaxCode": "ZP",
                            "Amount": 8.4
                        }, {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "TaxCode": "US1",
                            "Amount": 6.98
                        }]
                    },
                    "BaseFare": {
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "Amount": 93.02
                    },
                    "EquivFare": {
                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                        "Amount": 93.02
                    }
                },
                "Endorsements": {
                    "NonRefundableIndicator": true
                }
            }
        },
        "FareInfos": {
            "FareInfo": [{
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "Cabin": {
                        "Cabin": "Y"
                    },
                    "SeatsRemaining": {
                        "BelowMin": false,
                        "Number": 7
                    }
                },
                "FareReference": "B"
            }, {
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "Cabin": {
                        "Cabin": "Y"
                    },
                    "SeatsRemaining": {
                        "BelowMin": false,
                        "Number": 7
                    }
                },
                "FareReference": "B"
            }]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "DivideInParty": {
                "Indicator": false
            }
        },
        "ItinTotalFare": {
            "FareConstruction": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                "Amount": 93.02
            },
            "TotalFare": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                "Amount": "128.60"
            },
            "Taxes": {
                "Tax": [{
                    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                    "TaxCode": "TOTALTAX",
                    "Amount": 35.58
                }]
            },
            "BaseFare": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                "Amount": 93.02
            },
            "EquivFare": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                "Amount": 93.02
            }
        }
    },
    "TicketingInfo": {
        "ValidInterline": "Yes",
        "TicketType": "eTicket"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test is a Sandbox Environment for the purpose of testing API calls by Developers. This does not reflect real time availability and pricing.

Answer (score 1):

jmacagno you are absolutely correct.  The sandbox system has a snapshot of data that it uses for responses.